# django-paypal: IPN requests are always INVALID

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I'm using [dcramer's fork of django-paypal](https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal), but I always encounter an invalid IPN while working with my sandbox accounts.

I receive the following IPN:

```
Invalid postback. (INVALID)
```

I tried everything that showed up on google:

- checked seller & buyer emails
- sandbox accounts are both verified
- I use `form.sandbox` to render the paypal form
- tried removing custom values
- there is no non-ascii character in the request

When manually checking the request with https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr, I also get `INVALID`.

Did someone encounter this issue ? Is there any more-verbose page to validate ipn requests ?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I also get errors on post-back starting yesterday (18 June):

```
Opened POST Back Socket to PayPal.
PayPal Post Back returns HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 216
Expires: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 22:18:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 22:18:00 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#47;cgi&#45;bin&#47;webscr", is invalid.<p>
....
</BODY></HTML>
: not handled.
```

I use my own IPN integration. It tries to handle all replies from PayPal, which is why I get the last message (: not handled.) I made a package upgrade yesterday, so I'm not quite sure it is a PayPal problem though.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting a proper `INVALID` response, which is just a raw text containing the word. I get no html like you do. However, I'll try to make my own ipn view to see if it works better. I see that django-paypal suppresses `N/A` dates in the POST parameters, it could be the reason.

Comment: Your problem is that you're missing a 'Host' header in your IPN script. Simply ensure you add a 'Host: www.paypal.com' HTTP header and it'll go through normally.